# Problem opening custom config section in web.config

Tags: .net, asp.net

I am having some trouble opening a custom config section in my web.config file.

Here is web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>            
         <section name="ldapConfiguration" type="GTCC.Ldap.LdapConfiguration,GTCCLdap"/>
    </configSections>
    <ldapConfiguration PrimaryServer="1.2.3.4" SecondaryServer="5.6.7.6" Port="636" CertPath="c:\mycert.cer" AdminUsername="admin" AdminPassword="adminpass"/>
 </configuration>
```

Here is code to get the section:

```
    var config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/");
    var ldapConfig = (LdapConfiguration)config.GetSection("ldapConfiguration");
```

Here is the contents of config.Sections.Keys:

```
system.data
windows
system.webServer
mscorlib
system.data.oledb
system.data.oracleclient
system.data.sqlclient
configProtectedData
satelliteassemblies
system.data.dataset
startup
system.data.odbc
system.diagnostics
runtime
system.codedom
system.runtime.remoting
connectionStrings
assemblyBinding
appSettings
system.windows.forms
```

Why isn't my section showing up in the keys?

## EDIT

Error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Comment: That error message will appear?

Comment: Is there an InnerException on the Exception that you're seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code that gets the configuration object:

```
LdapConfiguration ldapConfig = (LdapConfiguration)ConfigurationSettings.GetConfig("ldapConfiguration");
```